# How to add a file to PbxGroupPsiElement - AppCode plugin development

Tags: intellij-plugin, appcode

I have a reference to `PbxGroupPsiElement`, and I'm trying to create a file inside using an action. To create a file I'm using following command: `PbxGroupPsiElement.getDirectoryPsiElement().createFile("Test.swift");`

It does create a file in directory, but in AppCode is not attached. How I can add it automatically to `PbxGroupPsiElement`?

Thank you.

Comment: Take a look at `PBXProjectFileManipulator.addFile()`

Comment: Appreciate pointing our the direction, I will the result of doing that as a response. Thank you for your great help!